# Sensor_Service cannont be resolved as a variable

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an error on sensor service. I'm pretty sure that's the right syntax, unless I'm missing something. Just need that part for the accelerometer. Greatly appreciate if you could post thoughts.

```
public class AskQuestions extends Fragment {

 private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private ShakeDetector mShakedetector;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_questions, container, false);
       //Error
        mSensorManager = getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        mShakedetector = new ShakeDetector(new OnShakeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                handleNewAnswer();
            }
        });



        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakedetector, mAccelerometer, 
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakedetector);
    }
    private void handleNewAnswer() {
        if(makeMethink == true) {
            result = answer.makeMeThink();
        }else if(WhatsTheAnswer == true){
            result =  answer.whatsTheAnswer();
        } else if (inspireMe){
            result = answer.inspireQuotes();
        }




                displayAnswer.setText(result);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

The problem is the code you used only works in a subclass of `Context` (e.g. `Activity`). `Fragment` is not a subclass of `Context`, so you have to get an object of that type in order to get the system service. Luckily, in a `Fragment`, you can easily get the container `Activity` with `getActivity()`.

SENSOR_SERVICE is a constant that is defined in `Context`, so you have to write `Context.SENSOR_SERVICE` whenever you use it from outside a subclass of `Context`.

Comment: Added an explanation.